# How to get a hierarchy table in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I would like to create a table that shows the hierarchy of another SQL Server table.
I have a table with the following structure

```
+-----------+----------+
| AccountID | ParentID |
+-----------+----------+
| 1         |          |
+-----------+----------+
| 2         | 1        |
+-----------+----------+
| 3         | 1        |
+-----------+----------+
| 4         | 2        |
+-----------+----------+
| 5         | 3        |
+-----------+----------+
| 6         | 5        |
+-----------+----------+
```

and would like to get another table with the following structure

```
+-----------+------+
| AccountID | Path |
+-----------+------+
| 1         | 1    |
+-----------+------+
| 2         | 1    |
+-----------+------+
| 2         | 2    |
+-----------+------+
| 3         | 1    |
+-----------+------+
| 3         | 3    |
+-----------+------+
| 4         | 1    |
+-----------+------+
| 4         | 2    |
+-----------+------+
| 4         | 4    |
+-----------+------+
| 5         | 1    |
+-----------+------+
| 5         | 3    |
+-----------+------+
| 5         | 5    |
+-----------+------+
| 6         | 1    |
+-----------+------+
| 6         | 3    |
+-----------+------+
| 6         | 5    |
+-----------+------+
| 6         | 6    |
+-----------+------+
```

Note: In the Parents ID field you must always include your own ID, i.e., 1-1, 2-2, etc.

If you see in the first table, for AccountID 1, there is no ParentID, because it is the highest hierarchical level. But in the table I need to extract, you see that for AccountID 1 the value 1 appears in the Path column. The same happens for the rest of the values, that is, for AccountID 2, in the result table AccountID 1 appears (its superior hierarchical value), but it is also necessary that it includes the value 2. And so for the rest of the values in the AccountID column.

Setup sample data:

```
create table Account 
(
  AccountID INT,
  ParentID INT NULL
 )

 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID, ParentID)
 VALUES
 (1, NULL),
 (2,1),
 (3,1),
 (4,2),
 (5,3),
 (6,5)
```

I'm not able to get this results. Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you had a look at an rCTE? There's plenty of them here on SO; why didn't those examples help you?

Comment: Just to clarify on @Larnu's comment, an rCTE is a Recursive Common Table Expression. It might help you narrow down the search ;) But yes, CTEs are extremely efficient when dealing with hierarchical data.

Comment: I reviewed several post with recursive CTE, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "In the Parents ID field you must always include your own ID, i.e., 1-1, 2-2" as this doesn't match your examples, Please explain how Path should be derived.

Comment: @SteveFord, for example, the resulting table must include for AccountID 1, the ParentID 1 field. 
For AccountID 2, it must include both ParentID 1 and ParentID 2. That is, it must always include a row with its own ID, in addition to the corresponding ParentIDs.

Comment: @Gonzalo please update your question to show exactly what you want as this is still not clear to me

Comment: @SteveFord. Thank you for your answer. If you see in the first table, for AccountID 1, there is no ParentID, because it is the highest hierarchical level. But in the table I need to extract, you see that for AccountID 1 the value 1 appears in the Path column. The same happens for the rest of the values, that is, for AccountID 2, in the result table AccountID 1 appears (its superior hierarchical value), but it is also necessary that it includes the value 2. And so for the rest of the values in the AccountID column.

Comment: Have you considered using the `hierarchyid` type to model your hierarchy instead? It trivially gives you access to things such as the whole path back to the root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, the easiest way to achieve this is with a rCTE, and the recurse *down* each level of the hierarchy until you get to the bottom:

```
--Sample Data
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT V.AccountID,
           V.[Path]
    FROM (VALUES(1,NULL),
                (2,1),
                (3,1),
                (4,2),
                (5,3),
                (6,5))V(AccountID,[Path])),
--Solution
rCTe AS(
    SELECT YT.AccountID AS RootID,
           YT.AccountID,
           YT.[Path]
    FROM YourTable YT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.RootID,
           YT.AccountID,
           YT.[Path]
    FROM rCTe r
         JOIN YourTable YT ON r.[Path] = YT.AccountID)
SELECT r.RootID AS AccountID,
       r.AccountID AS [Path]
FROM rCTe r
ORDER BY AccountId,
         [Path];
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2b933692216cc846135a09d01f917ac6)

Comment: You forgot the semi colon before the With.

Comment: @MarkKram huh? Why would there be a `;` before the `WITH`? `;` is a statement terminator, and there were no statements prior to the `WITH`. Even so, the `;` wouldn't go **before** the `WITH`, it would go **after** the prior statement. The only place there should be a `;` in the above is where there is one; after the end of the statement (`ORDER BY AccountId, [Path];`).

Comment: As a matter of habit i always add a semi colon before the With in the CTE because there are always statements before the CTE.

Comment: @MarkKram clearly not in the above, but that bodes you 2 questions: Why are you putting a `;` at the start of a `WITH` with `;` is a statement **terminator** not a "beginninator", and why aren't you properly terminating your other statements in the first place? It's not `DECLARE @I int = 10 {NewLine} ;WITH CTE AS...` it's `DECLARE @I int = 10; {NewLine} WITH CTE AS...`. The functionality that is deprecated is **not terminating** your statements with a semi-colon, not *"not beginning"* them with a semi-colon. (You wouldn't start your C# statements with a `;`, that would cause you errors.)

Comment: @Larnu. Thank you so much!. Your sentence worked fine adding a semi colon!.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this sentence, based on your sentence,

```
WITH rCTe AS (
    SELECT YT.Accountid AS RootID,
           YT.Accountid,
           YT.Parentaccountid
    FROM PBI_OrganizacionJerarquica YT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.RootID,
           YT.Accountid,
           YT.Parentaccountid
    FROM rCTe r
         JOIN PBI_OrganizacionJerarquica YT ON r.Parentaccountid = YT.Accountid)

SELECT r.RootID AS AccountID,
       r.Accountid AS [Path]
FROM rCTe r
ORDER BY AccountId,
         [Path];
```

and I get this error

Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Please avoid issues with a suggested answer as a new answer. That will confuse others who might stumble upon your question in the future. It's recommended to instead simply leave a comment below the answer you are replying to.